# ASPxGridView coloring

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

Is there a way to change all background colors of this control. Styles property has like 50 parts that can be changed, and although I think I changed all of them, I still have few parts with default color.

Is there a way to have ASPxGridView in one specific color, for example, I need it all blue.

Comment: Hi, are there specific parts that don't get colored? Have you looked at http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3727?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I wanted to format the DEVX Grid to match the boostrap theme of my site.

[Here is what I came up with at this link.](http://blog.regencysoftware.com/post/easy-change-style-of-devexpress-grid-to-match-bootstrap) Posted below..

```
<style>
  table
    {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
      font-size: 14px !important;
      color: #262626 !important;
   }

    tr:nth-child(even) {background: #EEEEEE}

  .dxgvDataRow_DevEx:hover  { background-color: #C0E0FF; } 
</style>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var Grid = $(".dxgvTable_DevEx");
        Grid.attr('style', "min-width:300px;max-width:750px;");
    });
</script>
```